# error occurs when updating a table in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE Bookdetails SET lastchapter = " + test + " WHERE bookpath=" +sentFilename; 
db.execSQL(updateQuery);
```

**Error:**

```
03-04 13:36:23.997: I/System.out(9722): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
near "/": syntax error: , while compiling: UPDATE Bookdetails SET lastchapter = 
mukund WHERE bookpath=/mnt/sdcard/Download/What's so great about the doctrine of 
 grace.epub errors happens
```

the error is posted above

My table contains the field id, bookpath and lastchapter, book path contains the values

```
 /mnt/sdcard/Download/What's so great about the doctrine of grace.epub  
  /mnt/sdcard/Download/1b4fdaac-f31d-41e8-9d15-26c9078d891f.epub 
  /mnt/sdcard/Download/Commentary on Romans.epub
```

and lastchapter contains the values nothing nothing nothing

id contains 1 2 3

why is the error occurring at `"/"` there is no hash in my update query it is only there at string which stores bookpath? Is this an error?

Comment: test is a string and its value is mukund

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String literals in SQL need to be in `''` quotes.

However, it's better to use `?` placeholders for literals like this:

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE Bookdetails SET lastchapter=? WHERE bookpath=?";
db.execSQL(updateQuery, new String[] { test, sentFilename });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your lastchapter & bookpath is of type String (TEXT). Hence when you are adding or updating it's value you should always use `'` ( Single cot ) around it. Change your query to this,

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE Bookdetails SET lastchapter ='" + test + "' WHERE bookpath='" +sentFilename + "'"; 
db.execSQL(updateQuery);
```

However, Direct Execution of SQL query is not advisable at developer.android.com hence you can use alternative way like below code,

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE Bookdetails SET lastchapter=? WHERE bookpath=?";
db.execSQL(updateQuery, new String[] { test, sentFilename });
```